# Laravel Sanctum issue

Tags: laravel-sanctum

I am implementing a REST API for laravel app. I have followed the laravel sanctum doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum. my problem is that when i protect the route like below, i am redirected to the login page.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function(){
    Route::get('extraitInfosKits/{user_id}', [KitController::class, 'extraitInfosKitsUtilisateur']);
});
```

The method extraitInfoskitsUtilisateur in my KitController is as follow

```
public function extraitInfosKitsUtilisateur($user_id){
        $kits = $this->kitRepository->extraitKitsUtilisateur($user_id);
        $detailsKits = $this->DetailsKitRepository->extraitDetailsKitsUtilisateur($user_id);
        $courss = $this->CoursRepository->extraitCoursKitsUtilisateur($user_id);
        $sectionsCourss = $this->SectionsCoursRepository->extraitSectionsCoursKitsUtilisateur($user_id);
        $sessionsCourss = ...
        ...
        ...
        $response = ['kits'=>$kits, 'detailsKits'=>$detailsKits, 'courss'=>$courss, 'sectionsCourss'=>$sectionsCourss, 'sessionsCourss'=>$sessionsCourss, 'evaluations'=>$evaluations, 'exercices'=>$exercices,
            'questions'=>$questions, 'optionsReponses'=>$optionsReponses, 'terminerSessions'=>$terminerSessions, 'tentatives'=>$tentatives, 'bilanCourss'=>$bilanCourss, 'bilanEvaluations'=>$bilanEvaluations,
            'bilanExercices'=>$bilanExercices, 'bilanQuestions'=>$bilanQuestions];
        return response($response, '200');
```

All the tuto i have red say i have to put the Accept = application/json header. I have done it butt i am still redirected to the login page.
When i remove the sanctum guard on the route, it works fine but when i put the sanctum middleware, i am redirected to the login page.

I have red everything on sanctum on Internet, everybody says the same thing, i see no specific config in the doc but it does not work for me.

Any help??

Comment: I want to underline that in my code, i save the token plaintext value. It is this plaintext value i use in postman

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the following line uncommented

```
\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
```

in app\Http\Kernel.php

```
'api' => [
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

It is in the official docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#sanctum-middleware)

Also, check in your .env file

```
 SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=localhost:8080
```

And in your REST client, remember to add to header

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```